# PoseStamped as flexbe app userdata

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am very new to the flexbe app and now I want to use the 'PublishPoseState' in my behavior, but I don't know how can I define a state machine user data with PoseStamped Type,
Is there any example or tutorial for that (obviously defining a string message is very simple)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262121/posestamped-as-flexbe-app-userdata/) by [Alireza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1637/alireza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 717 on 2017-05-19

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) on 2017-05-19**:
I'll be using FlexBE heavily next week so if nobody is able to help before then I'll let you know what I come across.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think this is not covered in one of the tutorials yet, but I am working on a new set of tutorials where this will be included.

You can use any ROS message or Python object as initial userdata by calling the object constructor in the value field of the "State Machine Userdata" panel of the Behavior Dashboard, e.g., `PoseStamped()`.

In addition, you need to make sure that the class is imported. This is done directly in the code. Click on "Edit Code" to open the source code and enter, e.g., `from geometry_msgs.msg import PoseStamped`, in the "manual import" section indicated at the top of the file.

There is also a "manual create" section further below which I would recommend to use to construct more complex objects and set values.

As a third choice, you can define a function in the "manual function" section, e.g.,

```
def pose(self, x, y):
    p = PoseStamped()
    p.pose.position.x = x
    p.pose.position.y = y
    return p
```

and then use something like `pose(1,2)` instead of `PoseStamped()` in the Dashboard as described above.

---

Originally posted by [Philipp Schillinger](https://answers.ros.org/users/24945/philipp-schillinger/) with karma: 321 on 2017-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alireza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1637/alireza/) on 2017-05-22**:
I already solved it, but thanks for your complete descriptions, I'm really looking forward to more tutorials. ;-)